# User keeps asking essentially the same question but not exact duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In the [webos](/questions/tagged/webos) tag we've got a user who keeps posting essentially the same question but they aren't exact duplicates.  Here's the latest in the series:

[Image not saving on a Palm device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923305/image-not-saving-on-the-palm-device)

Since they aren't exact duplicates I can't really flag them that way, but I'm not really sure what type of action is appropriate since it is a legit question but all these should be one question.

Any advice on what moderator action to request?

Comment: Your link seems to have gone AWOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He looks to be an inexperienced user who needs guidance. He has responded to comments on some of his posts, so maybe you can leave him some instructions on how to make his question better.

I think he could also benefit from a nice targetted Google search which turns up a couple of relevant tutorials. He's a beginner, but once you've shown him what to do he may change his approach and ask better questions. At the moment he is probably sitting there stuck and wondering why no-one answers him.

Comment: not a bad idea.  Okay, will give that a try and see if it helps.